# index column not being parsed as date

Tags: python, pandas

When I import a few records, the read_csv correctly reads the index column as date-time.
But if the number of records is more than a few thousand then the index column seems to be automatically changing to object instead of time.

```
import pandas as pd

myheader=['ticketId' ,  ... a lot of columns ... ,  'serialNo']

users=pd.read_csv('ticketold_head.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names = myheader, parse_dates={'datetime1' : ["ticketDate", "ticketTime"]}, keep_date_col=True,  index_col='datetime1')

In [36]: users.index
Out[36]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-04-06 10:48:49, ..., 2011-04-07 10:14:17]
Length: 10000, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

If there are too many records, the type of index is changed to object instead of datetime.

```
In [40]: users.index
Out[40]: Index([u'2011-04-06 10:48:49', u'2011-04-06 10:48:51', 
...
...
 u'2011-04-06 12:32:21', ...], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Are you sure all values are valid? Does it fail also if you do `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`?

Comment: It is still object and not time series even after using to_datetime method. Does it mean that I have non-valid dates? How will I know how many invalid dates are there? Is there any way to drop those records?

Comment: You have invalid date entries, you could do a binary chop on the data, find the number of rows, read the first half and then the second and keep going until you find the errant rows. Or you could read a line at a time and store the error lines that fail to convert.

Answer (score 1):

While a custom parser works, I think a faster path might be to do no parsing as you read the data in, the set the index like this.  The `coerce=True` forces bad values to `NaT`

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df["ticketDate"] + df["ticketTime"], coerce=True, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a function to check the date format. use it with to_read as date_parser=mydate

```
def mydate(x):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return pd.NaT
```